# CSS and html design for news feed like div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this image below in html and css, but I'm not sure how to get the vertical line to stay underneath the icons. Any help would get me started.

Please visit this link to see image:
[image]

Comment: You could use a background image and place the icons on top

Comment: You should edit your question and include the source code of what's been attempted so far. Or use http://jsfiddle.net/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Vertical timeline](http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/) -

The code uses a bit of JQuery as well as CCS3 (not sure if that would be OK for you)